# Will unchecking "Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation" effect author users or only my table designs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am given admin rights but I am trying out different layouts for purely development purposes. I am worried by unchecking it I might effect other server users?

Answer (score 1):

`“Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation”` is a `SQL Server Management Studio` option I believe.

`SQL Server Management Studio` or `SSMS` is a client tool. When you login to a server, Windows fire up an instance of SSMS specific to your login, any changes made to that will only be visible to you.